# Show that an even map on the circle $\mathbb S^1$ has even degree **without** any homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I want to show that an continuous even map, i.e., it satisfies $f(z)=f(-z)$, on the circle $\mathbb S^1$ has even degree **without** any homology techniques.

I know the multiplicative property of degrees, i.e., $\deg(f \circ g ) =\deg(f) \deg(g)$. It is trivial that if $f$ is an even map and $p_2$ is the multiplication map $z\mapsto z^2$, then $f\circ A=f$, $p_2\circ A= p_2$ where $A$ is the antipodal map. I also have a continuous map $g$ which satisfies $\deg(g)=\deg(f)$ and $p_2\circ f = g \circ p_2$. Given these information, how can I proceed?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $z\mapsto z^2$ gives a two sheeted covering of $S^1$ by $S^1$. Can you argue that if $f$ is even, it has a lift? 
If you can show that, it follows that $f=p\circ h$ where $p(z)=z^2$ for some $h.$ This immediately gives you that the degree of $f$ is even.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho Maybe because $f_*  \circ [w]= [\alpha]^2$ for some loop $\alpha$? ($w$ is the standard loop wrapping around once)

Comment: That's right, but I think proving that would be hard. I think the easiest way to show that $f$ has a lift is to observe that $f$ is constant on the fibers of $z\to z^2$ and therefore it factors through the cover.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho I am not aware of the factoring arguent yet. I think my $\alpha$ can be chosen to be the loop $f \circ \beta$ where $\beta$ is the path from $1\in \mathbb S^1$ to $-1$ in the counter-clockwise direction.

Comment: How do you define an 'even' map?

Comment: And which definition of degree do you use? Using a lift $\tilde f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with respect to $exp : \mathbb R \to S^1, exp(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$?

Comment: @PaulFrost It is defined by the lift of $f \circ w$ where $w: I \to S^1$ is the standard loop. I know that this is the same as the degree of the subgroup of the fund. group induced by $ f$.

Comment: If the map is smooth, this follows easily from counting preimages of a regular value since preimages come in pairs by evenness and either $f$ preserves orientation at both $z$ and $-z$ or at neither (this is because the antipodal map preserves orientation in dimension 1). In fact, you can homotope a continuous even map to a smooth even map, so this proves the statement in general, but this latter fact is rather technical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ to be the function
$$g(z)=f(\sqrt z).$$
The square root is defined up sign, but the fact that $f$ is even guarantees that $g$ is well-defined. In fact $g$ is continuous. For the covering projection $p=\exp(2\pi it(-)):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ is a quotient map, and $g\circ p$ is the continuous map
$$\mathbb{R}\ni t\mapsto f(\exp(\pi it))\in S^1.$$
Now if $p_2:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ is the map $p_2(z)=z^2$, then $g\circ p_2=f$. Thus
$$\deg(f)=\deg(g\circ p_2)=\deg(g)\cdot \deg(p_2)=2\cdot \deg(g).$$